# How to translate this into C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, events

I am still trying to translate stuff from VB to C# and my latest problem involves Events.  In the original Event file I have,

```
Public Event CommEvent As CommEventHandler
Public Delegate Sub CommEventHandler(ByVal source As Rs232, ByVal Mask As EventMasks)
```

Then call to the above,

```
Protected Sub OnCommEventReceived(ByVal source As Rs232, ByVal mask As EventMasks)
    Dim del As CommEventHandler = Me.CommEventEvent
    If (Not del Is Nothing) Then
        Dim SafeInvoker As ISynchronizeInvoke = Nothing
        Try
            SafeInvoker = DirectCast(del.Target, ISynchronizeInvoke)
        Catch
        End Try
        Try
            If (Not SafeInvoker Is Nothing) Then
                SafeInvoker.Invoke(del, New Object() {source, mask})
            Else
                del.Invoke(source, mask)
            End If
        Catch
            '!!! TO-DO
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Now if I use the VB to C# converter on the above, I get quite nicely,

```
public event CommEventHandler CommEvent;
public delegate void CommEventHandler(Rs232 source, EventMasks Mask);
```

And,

```
protected void OnCommEventReceived(Rs232 source, EventMasks mask)
{
    CommEventHandler del = this.CommEventEvent;
    if (((del != null))) {
        ISynchronizeInvoke SafeInvoker = null;
        try {
            SafeInvoker = (ISynchronizeInvoke)del.Target;
        } catch {
        }
        try {
            if (((SafeInvoker != null))) {
                SafeInvoker.Invoke(del, new object[] { source, mask });
            } else {
                del.Invoke(source, mask);
            }
        } catch {
            //!!! TO-DO
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is the CommEventEvent. There is no definition of this in the C# file yet it is in the original VB file and further, the code translator quite happily translates it.

Where does this come from please and how can I get it to work in the C# file?

Comment: Nope that's just it, the VB program refers to Me.CommEventEvent.  There is no declaration at all.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like this is simply referring to `CommEvent`:

```
CommEventHandler del = this.CommEvent;
```

I don't know why VB.NET let you refer to this as `CommEventEvent`. It could be one of those language shortcuts like how you can omit the word `Attribute` from the end of custom attributes or something.

Comment: I had previously replaced all the del's with this.CommEvent and it seemed okay but it seems so strange that I don't know whether I am doing the right thing.